# Why is it that my computer did not sleep nor hibernate, but it boots up quickly?

Tags: boot, sleep, windows-11

I've tweaked the settings in my computer so that it doesn't sleep or hibernate.

[image]

[image]

Yet I've discovered that when I leave my computer on overnight, it shuts off (power indicator light goes off). The following day when I press the power button again to turn on the computer, the computer boots instantly without having to take time to load startup applications.

[image]

Aside from sleep and hibernate, was there a third mode that the computer had entered into that allowed quick booting?

Where should I go to look what mode my computer has entered into? Is it the Event Viewer?

[image]

Comment: Fast Startup: https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1045548/

Comment: Look in Control Panel, Power settings to see if Wake Timers were set.

Comment: Its possible Windows Update installed updates, rebooted the computer and got to the lock screen. On the lock screen power management is different, and the computer will go to sleep.

Comment: I'm thinking if I can look for a log to see what mode Windows had entered into, that would be the quickest way... –

Comment: As @Mokubai states, it's likely Fast Startup, which can be turned off in BIOS -- and *should* be turned off, if you plan to dual-boot the PC.